# Can I apply @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) once globally instead of on each enum?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want all enums in my classes persisted by JPA as Strings, not ordinal.  Can I declare that globally someplace?  I'm using Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is no**.

Enum parameters are a compile time constants - there is no avenue to change them at runtime, and there's no way to craft a "project default".

Oddly, the only sane choice is `STRING`, mostly because `ORDINAL` is brittle; the order of your enums is forever locked in (data surgery notwithstanding), so I can't understand why the default is `ORDINAL` - I have never heard of any project using the it.

Comment: Right, there really should be some way to change that default from ordinal to String.  Otherwise you have to put @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)  before every enum.  Annoying.

Comment: A tiny bit neater: `import static javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING;` then just `@Enumerated(STRING)` at the usage site.